# How do I apply a `.link` setting?

Tags: systemd

I've set a `wireless.link` file in my `/etc/systemd/network` directory, according to the guide in `man systemd.link`. Is there a way to apply those settings without rebooting the system?

According to the manpage:

```
network link configuration is performed by the net_setup_link udev
builtin.
```

There's however no explanation about what this means.

Any hint?